# Select by location tool Vs layer.getFeatures(QgsRectangle(xmin,ymin...)))

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, extents, select-by-location

I can't make sense of the difference between:

1. QGIS Select by location tool (Vector->Research tools->Select by Location") which gives the correct result :7 records match the extent:

   [image: OOTB tool result of 7 intersected records]
2. Creating a custmised pyqgis tool that uses the extent of the canvas to create a QgsRectangle and uses the layer it gives 66 matching records...why? United Arab Emirates is nowhere close!

   Grab the extent from the input parameter (canvas extent) and force them to float, then:

   ```
   vlayer.selectByRect(QgsRectangle(xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax))
   features = [f for f in vlayer.getSelectedFeatures()]

   model_feedback.pushInfo("\nMatched selected features from extent intersection: {}\n".format(len(features)))
   ```

The countries layer is in WGS84, the project is in WGS84, the returned extent minx,miny,maxx,maxy is correct for the area I have around Denmark

[image: result from comparing canvas rectangle extent with countries]

Any ideas what's wrong or is there a bug at play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have made a mistake with the extent coordinates. This is what you used:

```
xmin = 6.550986341429791
xmax = 52.089222964702195
ymin = 14.6224323720
ymax = 58.35776867917401
```

Using the extents you mentioned, this is what it looks like on the map:

[image: Current map]

(where the pale pink shows the extent, the yellow country being Denmark).

But if we swap `xmax` with `ymin`:

```
xmin = 6.550986341429791
xmax = 14.6224323720
ymin = 52.089222964702195
ymax = 58.35776867917401
```

This is what it looks like on the map:

[image: ![Updated map]

(where the smaller pink box is the updated extent).

This should now match the countries you had when you used the `Select by Location` tool.

---

*For the record, I use Lurpak butter all the time.*

Comment: Well spotted!  thanks - that sorted it. The returned extent of the canvas was in a different order to the QgsRectangle specified order - or I accidentally swapped them.  PS I also use Lurpak all the time.

Comment: @GIS_py - Most welcome, glad it helped :)